# Codeigniter compiling a query

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi Codeigniter Experts.

I'm compiling a QUERY by several calls to a function.

When it is done I'll use the QUERY to retrieve some data of course.

Each call, calls another function which gets and returns some translations which is supposed to be used in the QUERY

But it seems like that the WHERE condition in translation funciton gets concatinated by the WHERE condition which I'm compiling in the main QUERY

```
private function add_to_asq($field_name, $values)
{
.
.
.
.
    $result = array();
    foreach( $values[$last_level] as $val )
    {
           foreach( $val as $v  )
           {
          $result[] = $this->db->escape( $this->asq_value_translate( $last_level, $v, $field_name ) );
        }
    }

    $this->db->where_in( sprintf( '%1$s' , $field_name  ) , implode( ',' , $result ) );

}


    private function asq_value_translate( $level, $value_md5 , $field_name )
    {   
        $this->db->select( sprintf( 'level_%1$d, level_%1$d_value' , $level ) )
        ->distinct()
        ->from('search_options_tree_view')
        ->where( sprintf( 'md5( level_%1$d_value ) = ' , $level ), $value_md5 )
        ->where( 'field_name' , $field_name );
        $q = $this->db->get();
        $value_name = sprintf( 'level_%1$d' , $level );
        $row = $q->row(0);
        $q->free_result();
        return $row->$value_name;       
    }
```

and the DB complains about it

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'type' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT DISTINCT `level_1`, `level_1_value` FROM (`search_options_tree_view`) WHERE 

`type` IN ('\'Forhandler\'')

 AND md5( level_1_value ) = '138be735c55896dbdbea9b6c5d503b6f' AND `field_name` = 'fuel'
```

Filename: C:\wamp\www\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

As you see the `type` IN ('\'Forhandler\'') has not anything to with the asq_value_translation.

Do you have a suggestion?

I've thought of cloning the db-object but then I thought that I ask first and shoot later.

Thanks a lot and have a nice time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$this->db->last_query()` to see what the output of your query actually is. Then take that query and run it in your db client to make sure the issue is not in codeigniter, but rather in your query.

Comment: I wish to use the framework to asseble the query. But it seems like that the WHERE is kind of global so to say. WHERE can be manipulated by any function before it is excuted.

Comment: Yea but if you use the last_query function, you can see what is being generated for the where clause and then modify as necessary.